# Read file, find pattern, edit and write back to same binary file

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file which has several lines of data, modify one of the lines and write back the edits into the same file I read from.

The file is located at a particular location on the PC and looks something like this:

```
"0000000000 55 4F 50 44 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 05 08 07 AA_BB584982"
```

This is one line of data and arbitrary numbers like this keep repeating in a similar pattern. I want to zero out only the `08 07` part only from the first line of this file. Any help/idea is much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Input files are in .bin format and they all do not necessarily have the same pattern but the location of values to be zeroed out is always the same across files. This is now more like counting bytes to modify instead of pattern match.

Comment: Here's what I do: read from the file line by line, append each line to a variable in order. When you reach the line you want to change, append the changed version to the var. In the end write the saved data to the file in another ```open```.

Comment: Modifying a file at a specific location is tricky.  Generally it's much easier to create a new file, copying lines from the original file and changing as needed, and then rename the new file to the original name when you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to modify according to pattern:

```
import re
from os import rename

path = r'/path/to/binary'
tmp_file = path + r'.mod'

pattern = b'\x55\x4F\x50\x44\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x05\x08\x07'
new_pat = b'\x55\x4F\x50\x44\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x05\xde\xad'

myre = re.compile(pattern)
with open(path, 'rb') as read_file, open(tmp_file, 'wb') as write_file:
    write_file.write(myre.sub(new_pat, read_file.read()))

rename(tmp_file, path)
```

Use this to modify according to location:

```
import struct
from collections import defaultdict
from os import rename

path = r'/tmp/rando_bin'
tmp_file = path + r'.mod'

location_start_hex = 0
location_end_hex = 8
fill_value = 0

mapper = defaultdict(set)
for hex_location in range(location_start_hex, location_end_hex + 1):
    mapper[hex_location // 2].add('right' if hex_location % 2 else 'left')


with open(path, 'rb') as read_file, open(tmp_file, 'wb') as write_file:
    byte_cnt = 0
    x = read_file.read(1)

    while x:
        if byte_cnt in mapper:
            if len(mapper[byte_cnt]) == 2:
                write_file.write(bytearray([fill_value]))
            elif 'left' in mapper[byte_cnt]:
                y = struct.unpack('B', x)[0]
                new_byte = y & int('00001111', 2)
                write_file.write(bytearray([new_byte]))
            else:
                y = struct.unpack('B', x)[0]
                new_byte = y & int('11110000', 2)
                write_file.write(bytearray([new_byte]))
        else:
            write_file.write(x)
        byte_cnt += 1
        x = read_file.read(1)

rename(tmp_file, path)
```

Some things to note about the modification by location script:

- Since python's `read()` can only read at a minimum by a size of 8bits and we need to modify by a size of 4bits (aka a nibble aka hex digit), care must be taken for the case when we only need to modify half what is read. This is what the `left` and `right` signify. They tell us to modify the left portion of the 8bits or the right portion of the 8bits.
- `left` and `right` could have been `0` and `1` but I left them like this to make the code somewhat easier to understand.
- The `location_start_hex` starts from `0` which translates to modifying the first hex digit.
- The hex digit located at `location_end_hex` is included in the modification.
- `read(1)` reads in 8bits at a time.
- You cannot modify any block of bits with this code. You can only modify a group of 4bits that is an offset of a multiple of 4 from the beginning of the binary. But this will suffice for this question.
- the `struct` (which is closely related to `C`'s `struct`) here is used to make the bits that are read in an integer which allows us to operate on it using bit-wise operations.

Comment: Works when I use a sample .txt file with the data I have on the question, but any idea how I would read and edit in-line if the input file were in binary format?

Comment: Updated answer for binary. Hopefully you realize that the pattern you provided in your question probably contains an address (first column) and some other information (last column) that need to be stripped/removed when comparing to the actual binary.

Comment: Understood, thanks for making it clear - I tried this and see an error message saying:    "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape" its somehow unable to read the file format.

Comment: Can you show the line that is causing this error? If your file name contains a `\ ` then you should use an r-string, e.g: `'C:\path\to\file.txt'` should be `r'C:\path\to\file.txt'` instead.

Comment: Complete error msg:    "File "C:\Users\Desktop\Docs\data.py", line 11
 with open ('C:\Users\Desktop\Docs\data.bin', 'rb') as read_file, open ('C:\Users\Desktop\Docs\data.bin', 'wb') as write_file:
 SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"  /* Tried replacing \ with / but that deleted all the bin file contents!

Comment: Hopefully, you have a backup for your binary! I did not mean to replace `\ ` with `/` . I meant you should place a `r` prior to your string. You should have: `with open (r'C:\Users\Desktop\Docs\data.bin', 'rb') as read_file, open (r'C:\Users\Desktop\Docs\data.bin', 'wb') as write_file`

Comment: Yes, had a backup of it! But same thing happens even with the    r'C:\path\to\file.bin' /*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194725/discussion-between-chmod-and-perplexabot).

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It's probably not the most efficient way to do it, but it should work.

```
file=open("your_file_here", "r")
data=file.read().split("\n")
file.close()
for i in data[0].split(" "):
    if i == "08" or i == "07":
        i = "00"
    else:
        pass
file = open("your_file_here", "w")
for i in data:
    file.write(i+"\n")
file.close()
```

Edit: I know I technically write a new file to the same location of the old file, but it should have the same effect as modifying it, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```py
input_file_path = r'C:\path\to\file.txt'
with open(input_file_path, 'r') as in_file:
    first_line, *rest = in_file.readlines()

first_line.replace('08 07', '00 00')

with open(input_file_path, 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join((first_line, *rest))
```

Should work.

Comment: Tried this & I get the following error msg:   File "C:\path\to\.py_script_file", line 17

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing..Could this be due to the input file format which is a '.bin'..?

Comment: I thought that your description of what the input file looked like was literal, but now I see that you were simply pasting what a hex editor would show you. I used string functions in my solution (```replace()``` and ```join()```) which won't work for binary data.

You should know that binary files don't really have "lines," so what you think is the first line of your file is really just the first X number of bytes of data of your file.

Comment: My bad..input file's path was used above, not the one to the script.

Comment: yes, you are right..its a bin file in fact. But would it make sense to convert this file to a different (.txt) format before editing it or is there a way to read the file directly in python?

Comment: I mean, all files are technically binary files. In Python's ```open()```, you choose whether to read it as bytes or text. The option ```open(file_path, 'r')``` opens as text, while ```open(file_path, 'rb')``` specifies to read it as binary. So you can simply use the latter call to open it directly, without having to do any conversion. I'm sure you can perform the edits you desire that way, but I have no experience directly editing binary files in Python.